# Get object instance class name with Qt's meta-object system

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmetaobject, qmetatype

I have 3 classes:

```
class Being : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Being(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};

class Animal : public Being {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Animal(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Dog(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};
```

Being's implementation is the following:

```
Being::Being(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    qDebug() << staticMetaObject.className();
}
```

I have the following code:

```
Being *pBeing = new Being();
Being *pAnimal = new Animal();
Being *pDog = new Dog();
```

Question is: is there a way to implement Being's constructor so that I can have access to the actual instance that points to my Being base class so that the log of the above code will be:

```
Being
Animal
Dog
```

?

**EDIT:**
My intention is that I want to be able to have a `Animal.txt`, `Being.txt` and `Doc.txt` that will be processed inside the Being base class. And I need to know, based on the instance's type, whether I need to parse `Animal.txt`, `Being.txt` or `Doc.txt` to get more information.

Does Qt support this? Is there a mechanism I can use to achieve this using C++/Qt? If not, could there be any elegant compromise solution for this?

Comment: Do you absolutely need this in the Being::Being constructor? Once the object is constructed you can refer to the metaobject, but that is not possible at that point (the enclosing object is not fully constructed yet)

Comment: Not necessarily in the constructor, but i need a mechanism to know, inside my Being class that the instance is of type `Being`, `Animal` or `Dog`...

Comment: If this is for debugging, that is just `metaObject->className()`. If you were planning to dispatch on the classname, use polymorphism instead.

Comment: No, it's not just for debugging, see my *edits*. I what an automatic mechanism that will gather more information based on the type of instance it was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in the constructor of `Being` because the enclosing object is not constructed yet, therefore metadata about it is not available. However, you can write the `initialize` method that should be called after the object construction, e.g. with print function:

```
class Being : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Being(QObject *parent = nullptr) { qDebug() << this->metaObject()->className(); }  // this will always print "Being"
    void initialize() { qDebug() << this->metaObject()->className(); }  // this will print the actual class name
};

class Animal : public Being {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Animal(QObject *parent = nullptr) { initialize(); }  // you can already use this method in the constructor
};

TEST(xxx, yyy)
{
    Being* being = new Being();
    Being* animal = new Animal();
    being->initialize();
    animal->initialize();  // or you can call it later
}
```

In case `initialize` method is not good solution, you can always hack it through `Being` constructor: `explicit Being(QString name, QObject* parent = nullptr;` and then `explicit Animal(QObject *parent = nullptr): Being("Animal") {}`, but I think it is less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

> My intention is that I want to be able to have a Animal.txt, Being.txt and Doc.txt that will be processed inside the Being base class. And I need to know, based on the instance's type, whether I need to parse Animal.txt, Being.txt or Doc.txt to get more information.

Never let a base class know anything about its subclasses. Ever.

No matter how tempting it might look like, do no do it (even if you find out how).

A class might have hundreds of subclasses. Take for example `QObject`. Should `QObject` (or could it possible) know about your reimplementation of `QMainWindow`?

So, whatever the reason for this design decision is, **change it!**

### Possible solutions

If the process algorithm of the text files is the same, regardless of the subclass, create a base class method to do the processing and call it from the subclasses.

If the algorithm depends on the subclass, make the method abstract, i.e. `virtual` and withouth implementation (`=0`), and let the implementation to the subclasses.